# Cannot find a setter for ~ItemBinding~ that accepts parameter type 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-databinding

> Cannot find a setter for
> <the_derek.dogstuff.databinding.DogItemBinding app:product> that
> accepts parameter type
> 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<the_derek.dogstuff.db.entity.DogEntity>'
> If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is
> annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.

I’ve been going line-by-line through my app for over two days now. I used the Google provided “BasicSample” Android Room app to mock up my own app but am getting this error when I include this in my dog_fragment.xml

```
<include
 layout="@layout/dog_item"
 app:product="@{dogViewModel.dog}" />
```

The “dog_item” layout (dog_item.xml) is for showing a list of dogs, when you then click on it, it will bring you to a dog details screen (dog_fragment.xml). Without it, everything works great but it’s missing the “dog” tile to play into the details screen, and will only show a list of chew_toys.

> dog_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  
  <data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    
    <variable
      name="isLoading"
      type="boolean" />
    
    <variable
      name="dog"
      type="the_derek.dogstuff.viewmodel.DogViewModel" />
  </data>
  
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    
    <include
      layout="@layout/dog_item"
      app:product="@{dogViewModel.dog}" />
    
    <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
      
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_loading_chew_toys"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/loading_chew_toys"
        app:visibleGone="@{isLoading}" />
      
      <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/chew_toys_list_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/chew_toy_list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:contentDescription="@string/cd_chew_toys_list"
          app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
          app:visibleGone="@{!isLoading}" />
      </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

> DogFragment.java

```
public class DogFragment extends Fragment {

 private static final String TAG = "\t\tDogFragment";
 private static final String KEY_DOG_ID = "dog_id";

 private final ChewToyClickCallback mChewToyClickCallback =
   chewToy -> {
    // no-op
   };
 private DogFragmentBinding mBinding;
 private ChewToyAdapter mChewToyAdapter;

 public static DogFragment forDog(int dogId) {
  DogFragment fragment = new DogFragment();
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.putInt(KEY_DOG_ID, dogId);
  fragment.setArguments(args);
  return fragment;
 }

 @Nullable
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(
   @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
   @Nullable ViewGroup container,
   @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.dog_fragment, container, false);
 
  mChewToyAdapter = new ChewToyAdapter(mChewToyClickCallback);
  mBinding.chewToyList.setAdapter(mChewToyAdapter);
  return mBinding.getRoot();
 }

 @Override
 public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  DogViewModel.Factory factory =
    new DogViewModel.Factory(
      requireActivity().getApplication(), requireArguments().getInt(KEY_DOG_ID));
  final DogViewModel model =
    new ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(DogViewModel.class);

  mBinding.setLifecycleOwner(getViewLifecycleOwner());
  mBinding.setDogViewModel(model);

  subscribeToModel(model);
 }

 private void subscribeToModel(final DogViewModel model) {
  model
    .getChewToys()
    .observe(
      getViewLifecycleOwner(),
      chewToyEntities -> {
       if (chewToyEntities != null) {
        mBinding.setIsLoading(false);
        mChewToyAdapter.submitList(chewToyEntities);
       } else {
        mBinding.setIsLoading(true);
       }
      });
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroyView() {
  mBinding = null;
  mChewToyAdapter = null;
  super.onDestroyView();
 }
}
```

> DogViewModel.java

```
public class DogViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

  private static final String TAG = "\t\tDogViewModel";
  private final LiveData<DogEntity> mObservableDog;
  private final LiveData<List<ChewToyEntity>> mObservableChewToys;

  public DogViewModel(
      @NonNull Application application, DataRepository repository, final int dogId) {
    super(application);
    mObservableChewToys = repository.loadChewToysById(dogId);
    mObservableDog = repository.loadDog(dogId);
  }

  public LiveData<List<ChewToyEntity>> getChewToys() {
    return mObservableChewToys;
  }

  public LiveData<DogEntity> getDog() {
    return mObservableDog;
  }

  public static class Factory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

    @NonNull private final Application mApplication;

    private final int mDogId;

    private final DataRepository mRepository;

    public Factory(@NonNull Application application, int dogId) {
      mApplication = application;
      mDogId = dogId;
      mRepository = ((DogApp) application).getRepository();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    @NonNull
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
      return (T) new DogViewModel(mApplication, mRepository, mDogId);
    }
  }
}
```

> BindingAdapters.java

```
public class BindingAdapters {
  @BindingAdapter("visibleGone")
  public static void showHide(View view, boolean show) {
    view.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
  }
}
```

> DogClickCallback.java

```
public interface DogClickCallback {
 void onClick(Dog dog);
}
```

> dao query

```
@Query("select * from dog_table where id = :dogId")
LiveData<DogEntity> loadDog(int dogId);
```

> DogAdapter.java

```
public class DogAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DogAdapter.DogViewHolder> {
 private static final String TAG = "\t\tDogAdapter";

 @Nullable private final DogClickCallback mDogClickCallback;
 List<? extends Dog> mDogList;

 public DogAdapter(@Nullable DogClickCallback clickCallback) {
   Log.i(TAG, "DogAdapter: public constructor");
   mDogClickCallback = clickCallback;
   setHasStableIds(true);
 }

 public void setDogList(final List<? extends Dog> dogList) {
   if (mDogList == null) {
    mDogList = dogList;
    notifyItemRangeInserted(0, dogList.size());
   } else {
    DiffUtil.DiffResult result =
       DiffUtil.calculateDiff(
          new DiffUtil.Callback() {
            @Override
            public int getOldListSize() {
             return mDogList.size();
            }
            @Override
            public int getNewListSize() {
             return dogList.size();
            }
            @Override
            public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
             return mDogList.get(oldItemPosition).getId()
                == dogList.get(newItemPosition).getId();
            }
            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
             Dog newDog = dogList.get(newItemPosition);
             Dog oldDog = mDogList.get(oldItemPosition);
             return newDog.getId() == oldDog.getId()
                && TextUtils.equals(newDog.getName(), oldDog.getName());
            }
          });
    mDogList = dogList;
    result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
   }
 }

 @Override
 @NonNull
 public DogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   DogItemBinding binding =
      DataBindingUtil.inflate(
         LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.dog_item, parent, false);
   binding.setCallback(mDogClickCallback);
   return new DogViewHolder(binding);
 }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DogViewHolder holder, int position) {
   holder.binding.setDog(mDogList.get(position));
   holder.binding.executePendingBindings();
 }

 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
   return mDogList == null ? 0 : mDogList.size();
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
   return mDogList.get(position).getId();
 }

 static class DogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   final DogItemBinding binding;
   public DogViewHolder(DogItemBinding binding) {
    super(binding.getRoot());
    this.binding = binding;
   }
 }
}
```

---

---

(DogEntity also has Dog model class, if that helps)
I've tried Invalidate Caches/Restart, I've tried Clean Project, Rebuild Project. I've started a new project and copied my files into it.
Ooh, also, this is an error in addition:

```
import the_derek.dogstuff.databinding.DogFragmentBindingImpl;
```

It tells me it cannot resolve **DogFragmentBindingImpl**
I don't know how it's not getting generated but I assume the problems are intertwined. I don't know if I missed putting any code that could help, please let me know.

(modeled after)
[android architecture-components-samples](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/BasicSample)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I spent weeks or a month thinking that "app:product" was some sort of standard phrase or convention for XML. I thought "product" was a generic term used like "gravity" or "layout"..... if you get what I'm saying. Because when I posted the question I was new to Android, I never thought that the term after "app:" needed to be changed depending on the variable in data.

```
<include
     layout="@layout/dog_item"
     app:dog="@{dogViewModel.dog}" />
```

Comment: What is the point of this solution? I'm having a similar problem with an `<include ...>` layout and I don't get what is your solution helping to.

Answer (score 1):

This is [binding adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) error. If you write 'app:product' in your XML, there has to be binding adapter inside one of your kotlin or java classes with the name of 'product'. For example, for your

> app:product="@{dogViewModel.dog}"

there needs to be something like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("product")
fun yourFunctionName(yourViewType: YourViewType, data: List<DogEntity>?) {
    // your binding code here
}
```

Read more about data binding and binding adapters.

Comment: As I was attempting to send the variable to another layout (in the "include), the value after "app:" needed to be whatever the variable was named in the "<data> section of the xml.

Answer (score 1):

[the derek Fawcett's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63601993) is telling you that the parameter name inside the include-tag has to match the variable name used inside the included layout.

```
<include
     layout="@layout/dog_item"
     app:dog="@{dogViewModel.dog}" />
```

*dog_item*

```
<data>
    
    <variable
      name="dog"
      type="$path.DogClass" />

</data>
```

There are no general parameter names to match variables when it comes to bindings, you can define the names yourself and then set them accordingly.

Answer (score -4):

You're passing in a LiveData object here:

```
app:product="@{dogViewModel.dog}"
```

You need to pass in:

```
app:product="@{dogViewModel.dog.value}"
```

Comment: It's suppose to load in the dog entity, with all the details/chew toys below it.
Also, if I change it to "@{dogViewModel.dog.value}" (eg - String), it will tell me :
"Cannot find a setter for ... DogItemBinding app:product> that accepts parameter type 'java.lang.String'"

Comment: Try "@{dogViewModel.getDog().value}"

Comment: just .getDog() or .getDog()value yields the same exact error :-(

Comment: Just discovered, on the Basic Sample App from Google, if I change that field in their.

< product_fragment.xml .

from
`<include
            layout="@layout/product_item"
            app:product="@{productViewModel.product}" />`
to
`<include
            layout="@layout/product_item"
            app:product="@{productViewModel.product.id}" />`

it yields the same exact error message I get